# Why does Visual studio 2013 ignores 'public' when creating a class + Interface

Tags: visual-studio

As the question says, why does VS2013 do this?

Instead of

```
public interface IName
```

When created it does,

```
interface IName
```

Asking as it may be a setting that I haven't got. Its just annoying when trying to reference classes and interfaces!!

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean? Do you have a code sample? I've never noticed anything like this

Comment: What do you mean "ignores public"?

Comment: Sorry, just updated with some code, its really stupid, the question will be closed, but it just slows me down

Comment: Sharing the class shouldn't be the default anyway. Creating shared classes requires a bit more forethought than just file->new. That's my opinion anyway. Anyway, it's just a default, you can change the file if you'd like.

Comment: But it does it when the 1st class is created, like from a blank solution

Comment: Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code` (for Visual Studio 2013) and change the templates there. Not the best solution but it works. Or you can go to your documents folder, and into the Visual Studio folder found there and add your own new templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because:

> Interface members are automatically public, and they can't include any access modifiers

[From Interfaces C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Comment: Though that is true (and thanks) but when I remove public from the interface, and try to reference it, I get an compiler error of 'Interface is inaccessible because of its protection level'. If Interfaces are automatically public, why do I need to declare it?

Comment: I dont know what you are doing (maybe that is a better thing to post above)  But interfaces work fine without the public in from of them.

Comment: Actually, thats right, I tried it in the same project and yes you dont need to use public, but I am trying to reference the interface from a different project, so even though I include the namespace at the top of the class, I still need public. weird

Comment: Ok its something to do with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390395/vb-cannot-access-class-from-different-project-same-solution

maybe to do with assemblies. Ok problem solved! cheers!